# Value from ASP MVC controller to Silverlight textbox

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-2, silverlight-3.0

Is there a way to pass a single string value from ASP MVC controller to a silverlight textBox?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make your type scriptable as follows:

```
[ScriptableType]
public partial class MainPage : UserControl
{

    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        HtmlPage.RegisterScriptableObject("MainPage", this);
    }

    [ScriptableMember]
    public string Text
    {
        get { return TextBox1.Text; }
        set { TextBox1.Text = value; }
    }

}
```

Now you have access to `MainPage.Text` property.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    Silverlight.createObjectEx({
        source: '/clientbin/journal.web.administration.xap',
        parentElement: document.getElementById('SilverlightPlaceHolder'),
        id: 'SilverlightPlugin',
        properties: {
            version: '4.0.60129.0'
        },
        events: {
            onLoad: function () {
                var host = document.getElementById('SilverlightPlugin');
                if (host != null)
                    host.content.MainPage.set_Text('@ViewBag.Text');
            }
        }
    });
</script>
```

And finally return string from action like this:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    ViewBag.Text = "Some Text";

    return View("Index");
}
```

**Update:** If you are using ASP.NET MVC 2, you have to change the `ViewBag.Text` to ViewData["Text"] and in markup, change the `@ViewBag.Text` to `<%: ViewData["Text"] %>`.

Comment: Thanks. I was able to do this by setting the initparm value also , but this seems to be a better approach.